Column Chart is not showing any columns inside our prod app. any advice
I have a Column Chart inside a gallery , and it is working well on our Test app (which is connected to the test sharepoint site), as follow:-

but on our PROD app which is connected to the PROd sharepoint site, the chart will not show any column as follow:-

any advice what could be causing this issue?
Thanks
